# Using WebStorm with `built` folder for running tests in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I want to be able to use WebStorm to run my unit tests for an Angular 2 project like this....

[image]

But because I am doing Angular 2 (with TypeScript) when I update my files WebStorm doesn't know to re-run the tests. The reason for this is that I am pre-compiling the app into a `/built/` folder and serving it from there.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`auto-test` option can only work if the source you're editing is loaded by karma. In your project, karma seems to be using files from a `/built/` folder.
So, to make re-running work for your case, special integration with `karma watch` is needed. Please vote for [WEB-14437](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14437)